# Understanding target_tags and firewall_networks of the GCP's Load Balancer Terraform module

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp, gcp-load-balancer

I'm trying to understand the `target_tags` and `firewall_networks` fields of the `GoogleCloudPlatform/lb-http/google` Terraform module.

For the `target_tags`, the documentation says: "List of target tags for health check firewall rule [...]". I find it confusing as the firewall rule for the health check defines its own `target_tags`. If I understand correctly, the rule is applied to the machines with this specific tag, for example, from a template within a MIG. Consider the following:

```
module "instance_template" {
  source = "terraform-google-modules/vm/google//modules/instance_template"
  // ...
  tags = ["allow-hc"]
}

resource "google_compute_firewall" "allow-hc-rule" {
  name          = "allow-health-check"
  project       = var.pro
  direction     = "INGRESS"
  network       = google_compute_network.my-network.self_link
  source_ranges = ["130.211.0.0/22", "35.191.0.0/16"]
  target_tags   = ["allow-hc"]
  allow {
    ports    = ["80"]
    protocol = "tcp"
  }
}
```

In such a case, machines from the template are tagged with the `allow-hc` tag and the `allow-hc-rule` is applied to them, allowing the health check. Thus, what shall be put in the LoadBalancer's `target_tags`?

```
module "gce-lb-http" {
  source            = "GoogleCloudPlatform/lb-http/google"
  project           = var.pro
  target_tags       = ["allow-hc"] // Is this correct?
  firewall_networks = [google_compute_network.my-network.name] // What additional firewall rules will be created in this network?
}
```

Next, the `firewall_networks` field of the Load Balancer Module. The doc says: "Names of the networks to create firewall rules in". I don't get it. How the load balancer configuration determines which firewall rules are added to the network? Moreover, which firewall rules are added to the named network? If I add `my-network` there, what firewall rules will be added to this network?

Answer (score 0):

**I find it confusing as the firewall rule for the health check defines its own target_tags.**

A tag is an identifier which helps you to configure allow or deny policies to multiple resources, go through this google official [doc](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/tags/tags-creating-and-managing) for more information. Target tags won’t get created automatically unless they are enabled by some cloud function or some terraform script already has them because of org policy.

**In such a case, machines from the template are tagged with the allow-hc tag and the allow-hc-rule is applied to them, allowing the health check. Thus, what shall be put in the LoadBalancer's target_tags?**

Load balancer's target tags are similar to that of MIG's these define what firewall rules are to be added for enabling healthcheck of your load balancers and for more info on healthcheck rules for  loadbalancer refer to this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/health-check-concepts).

**The doc says: "Names of the networks to create firewall rules in". I don't get it. How the load balancer configuration determines which firewall rules are added to the network? Moreover, which firewall rules are added to the named network? If I add my-network there, what firewall rules will be added to this network?**

Loadbalancers are used both internally and externally, you need respective [firewall rules](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/firewall-rules) for having a proper configuration in place.

Comment: @RobertSzooba can you check and update whether this has answered your queries...